# Prove convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

$\{X_n\}$ and $\{X\}$ are random variables defined on $(S,σ,P)$ with $E(X_n^2)<\infty$, for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$, and $E(X)<\infty$. If
$E\left((X-X_n)^2\right)<\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, then I'd like to show that the sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges to $\{X\}$ in probability as $n\to\infty$.

My teacher asked me to use convergence in moments however I am not able to make any progress in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your post.

If

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n-X]^2=0$$

That is

$$X_n\xrightarrow{L^2}X$$

than it is also

$$X_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}X$$

---

Proof:

---

Using Chebishev inequality we get

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\{|X_n-X|\leq \epsilon\}\geq 1-\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n-X]^2}{\epsilon^2}$$